# Visual Studio, Intel Visual Fortran, and Visual C/C++ mixed-language compile

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, cuda, fortran

Working with Visual Studio 2008 Pro, with Intel Fortran compiler v11, on Windows 7 x64.

I have an Intel Visual Fortran project set up with all the fortran source files. I wish to gradually replace all these subroutines with C/C++ (actually cuda -- bonus points). Simply right clicking on source files in the solution explorer and "add existing item" will put a .cpp or .c or cuda file in the list... but it never gets compiled. Thus any INTERFACE to C code written into the fortran code always fails on the link step.

How does one get a mixed-language project like this? Google has failed me, and all I find are descriptions of the actual interface code, with no instructions on how to implement the visual studio build system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're adding .c / .cpp files in a fortran project, if I've not misunderstood ?

A solution can contain projects in several languages but a project must be in one language.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake, thank you. I probably should've read those last two paragraphs in the Visual Fortran doc, huh?

Comment: Here's an example of setting up a mixed language solution for VC++ 2010 and CUDA. It might be of some help. http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/03/using-cuda-and-thrust-with-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 1):

A Visual Studio project can only contain code elements from a single language. To mix C++, CUDA and Fortran, you must set up a Visual Studio Solution. Then you are free to integrate multiple languages.

A useful guide to setting up a CUDA multi-language VS 2010 Solution can be found [here](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/03/using-cuda-and-thrust-with-visual-studio-2010/).

[This answer has been assembled from comments and added as a community wiki to get this question off the unanswered list for the CUDA tag].